# ANTLR4 PLSQL Grammar Python 3 Missing Function

Tags: python, parsing, plsql, antlr4, lexer

I'm using this grammar https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/plsql for Antlr4 but I'm getting an error because its referring to a function that does not exist.

> 'NameError: name 'IsNewlineAtPos' is not defined '

I can see that someone has updated the csharp version two files (that are extra items? Base lexer and Parser? That include an update that refers to the function in the below code.

```
// https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve034.htm#SQPUG054
REMARK_COMMENT:      'REM' {IsNewlineAtPos(-4)}? 'ARK'? (' ' ~('\r' | '\n')*)? NEWLINE_EOF -> channel(HIDDEN);

// https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve032.htm#SQPUG052
PROMPT_MESSAGE:      'PRO' {IsNewlineAtPos(-4)}? 'MPT'? (' ' ~('\r' | '\n')*)? NEWLINE_EOF;

// TODO: should starts with newline
START_CMD
    //: 'STA' 'RT'? SPACE ~('\r' | '\n')* NEWLINE_EOF
    // https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12002.htm
    // https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch12003.htm
    : '@' {IsNewlineAtPos(-2)}? '@'? ~('\r' | '\n')* NEWLINE_EOF
    ;
```

This is the update on git

https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/commit/94887a3f4c9040578ef01b561e1d5e0ec54cbe9b

I'm using Python to run this and would appreciate if someone could tell me why they 'extend' and what this function they create does. (and if they can show me how to convert to python 3 that would be awesome)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{...}?` parts are called [semantic predicates](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/predicates.md) and contain target specific code (Python in your case). So, that means `IsNewlineAtPos(...)` should be a function defined in a Python-flavored `PlSqlBaseLexer`, just like there is a `PlSqlBaseLexer` implementations for [C#](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/plsql/CSharp) and [Java](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/plsql/Java):

```python
# TODO import ANTLR's runtime classes here

class PlSqlBaseLexer(Lexer):

  __init__(self, ...):
    # TODO

  def IsNewlineAtPos(self, pos):
    # TODO
```

Normally, ANTLR creates a lexer from your grammar that extends ANTLR's own `Lexer` class, but since the PL-SQL grammar needs a bit more target specific code, the following is added to the grammar:

```antlr
options {
    superClass=PlSqlBaseLexer;
}
```

which tells ANTLR that it needs to create a `PlSqlBaseLexer` that "sits" between ANTLR's own `Lexer` implementation and the `PlSqlLexer`. So instead of this inheritance tree:

```
Lexer
 '- PlSqlLexer
```

it now becomes:

```
Lexer
 '- PlSqlBaseLexer (including the `IsNewlineAtPos` function)
   '- PlSqlLexer
```

So there's really not more to it than copying what was done for the Java (or C#) version. Looking at the Java implementation:

```java
protected boolean IsNewlineAtPos(int pos)
{
    int la = _input.LA(pos);
    return la == -1 || la == '\n';
}
```

combined with the predicate `{IsNewlineAtPos(-4)}?`, then the predicate will succeed when 4 characters back from the lexer's current character position (hence the minus 4) is -1 (nothing/EOF) or a newline character.

Also note the [Usage, important note](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/tree/master/plsql#usage-important-note) section in the README.

Comment: Thats a great detailed response! and fast too. Thank you. Any place I can go to read about creating Base Lexers? Its not in the Antlr 4 book ..

Comment: @SpencerAttridge checkout my EDIT where I added a bit more info about the `superClass`

Comment: first is my BaseParser effort and the second BaseLister.. but still issues... I'm afraid I'm just floundering.

`import sys
from typing.io import TextIO
from antlr4 import *

class PlSqlBaseParser(Parser):
    def __init__(self, input:TokenStream, output:TextIO = sys.stdout):
        super().__init__(input)
        

import sys
from antlr4 import *

class PlSqlBaseLexer(Lexer):
    def __init__(self,CharStream,output):
        super().__init__(input)
    def IsNewlineAtPos(self,pos):
        if self._input.LA(pos) -1:
            if la == '\n':
                return True`

Comment: Look closely at the Java and C# example classes `PlSqlBase...`: there's one for a lexer and one for the parser. The `IsNewlineAtPos(...)` function should be placed in the lexer.

Comment: Looking at the examples , I compare with anltr4's generated PlSqlParser init  and parse values and I see more there.... 

def __init__(self, input:TokenStream, output:TextIO = sys.stdout):
        super().__init__(input, output)

And when I try to create the baseparser, I have to pass in "Parser"  in the class and then more than one argument in the __init__ ... otherwise I get an error running the code. 

TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: I recommend creating a new question: your original question is answered (I think), and you now have a different issue: extending your own Python lexer. In your new question, you can then post the Python code and error messages. These small comment boxes are not suited for extensive Q&A's.

Comment: @SpencerAttridge I posted a small demo in your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52673751/antlr4-python-3-print-or-dump-tokens-from-plsql-grammar HTH